# Finding child-components from a parent, and listening on their events

Tags: angular, storybook

In a storybook setting, I'm trying to wrap regular Angular components and listen on state changes then make a JSON representation of the state in a TextArea so that the likes of Cypress/Selenium can assert on the JSON at the end of a test.

Here is how close I am. New component TestWrapper.ts:

```js
/* eslint-disable @angular-eslint/no-empty-lifecycle-method */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function */
import {
  AfterViewChecked,
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  Input,
  QueryList,
  ViewChildren
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'test-wrapper',
  template: '<div><ng-content/><pre><textarea rows="4" cols="80" id="dump">{{dump}}</textarea></pre></div>'
})
export class TestWrapper implements AfterViewChecked {

  @ViewChildren(ElementRef) children?: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if (this.children != undefined) {
      this.children.changes.pipe().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(">>>>>> event")
        this.dump = JSON.stringify(data)
      });
      // this is always zero
      console.log(">>>>>> CHILDREN defined " + this.children.length)
    } else {
      console.log(">>>>>> CHILDREN undefined")
    }
  }

  // This is the <pre><textarea>
  @Input() dump: string = "";

}
```

This in the Storybook source:

```js
export default {
  title: 'Heading/Sub Heading',
  component: ComponentUnderTest,
  argTypes: {
    client: {
      description: 'blah blah blah',
    },
    onASpecificComponentEvent: {
      description:
        'Output event raised when a blah blah blah',
      action: onASpecificComponentEvent,
    },
  },
  decorators: [
    componentWrapperDecorator(TestWrapper, ({args}) => ({
      parentText: args.parentText,
      onASpecificComponentEvent: args.onASpecificComponentEvent
    })),
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [],
      declarations: [ TestWrapper ],
    }),
  ]
} as Meta<ComponentUnderTest>;
```

The component renders fine, the text area is underneath it.  The debugging output is in the console. "CHILDREN defined" is always zero though. Seems that `QueryList<ElementRef>` isn't finding child components. Or `ngAfterViewChecked` is the wrong lifecycle to tap into. I tried `ngAfterContentChecked` too.  The `TestWrapper` would be re-used for every storybook presented component. The `componentWrapperDecorator(..)` code would be repeated for each, as event names change. No big deal as that's a small addition to existing code.

So the question in summary - how to attach listeners to child components from a generic parent.

I have this working for React & Storybook (and Cypress), but Angular+Storybook seems just out of reach.

Comment: If you're using <ng-content> I imagine you need use [ContentChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren). NOTE: I'm not pretty sure you can "reach" `ElementRef` -perhafs use a directive that add to all the components you want listen-

Comment: I change the declaration to `@ContentChildren` from `@ViewChildren` and it was the same: zero children.  I'll look at other directives, thanks.